# Como diferençar Aposto x Predicativo do Sujeito

Tags: gramática, sujeito

Recentemente, estava eu procurando algumas frases para analisar sintaticamente e, ao encontrar duas frases semelhantes, analisei os termos destacados da seguinte forma: *adjunto adnominal* e *predicativo do sujeito*, respectivamente

> O homem **nervoso** entrou no banco.

> O  homem, **nervoso**, entrou  no  banco.

Porém, corrigiram-me afirmando que o correto é *adjunto adnominal* e *aposto*, respectivamente.

Afinal de contas, o termo destacado entre vírgulas é um *predicativo do sujeito* ou um *aposto*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É predicativo do sujeito. Este tipo de casos vem tratado na *Nova Gramática do Português Contemporâneo* de Celso Cunha e Lindley Cintra (Lisboa, 2014, p. 210-11). Essencialmente a diferença é que o aposto designa a mesma entidade que o termo a que se refere, como *um turista inglês* em:

> O homem, **um turista inglês**, entrou no banco.

Se substituirmos *um turista inglês* por *nervoso* ou outro adjetivo, então já não será aposto, mas sim predicativo do sujeito, pois designa apenas uma característica do homem e não o próprio homem. Passo a citar a *Nova Gramática*:

> **Aposto e predicativo**
>
> Com o APOSTO atribui-se a um substantivo a propriedade representada por outro substantivo. Os dois termos designam sempre o mesmo ser, o mesmo objeto, o mesmo facto ou a mesma ideia.
>
> Por isso, o APOSTO não deve ser confundido com o adjetivo que, em função de PREDICATIVO, costuma vir separado do substantivo que modifica por uma pausa sensível (indicada geralmente por vírgula na escrita). Numa oração como a seguinte:
>
> > E a noite vai descendo **muda e calma…** (Florbela Espanca, *S*, 60.)
>
> que também poderia ser enunciada :
>
> > E a noite, **muda e calma**, vai descendo…
>
> ou:
>
> > E, **muda e calma**, a noite vai descendo…
>
> *muda e calma* é PREDICATIVO de um predicado verbo-nominal.

Dependendo do contexto, o nosso exemplo pode enquadrar-se neste caso. Teríamos então:

> O homem, **nervoso**, entrou no banco = O homem entrou **nervoso** no banco

Neste caso, *nervoso* apenas descreve o estado do homem quando entrou no banco. Outra possibilidade é *nervoso* indicar a causa de ele ter entrado no banco, como em:

> O homem passava à frente do banco quando foi assediado por marginais. Então o homem, **nervoso**, entrou no banco.

Neste caso, *nervoso* equivale a *porque ficou nervoso* ou *porque era nervoso*. Este é o caso que a *Nova Gramática* trata de seguida:

> O mesmo raciocínio aplica-se à análise de orações elípticas, cujo corpo se reduz a um adjetivo que nelas desempenha a função de PREDICATIVO. É o caso de frases do tipo:
>
> > **Rico**, desdenhava dos humildes.
>
> em que *rico* não é aposto. Equivale a uma oração adverbial de causa [= *porque era rico*], dentro da qual exerce função de PREDICATIVO.

Este exemplo da *Nova Gramática* poderia estar melhor explicado. Obviamente, *rico* tem de se referir a alguém mencionado anteriormente, tipo, “Vasco, rico, desdenhava dos humildes”. A *Nova Gramática* remata com:

> O adjetivo, enquanto adjetivo, «não pode exercer a função de APOSTO, porque designa *uma característica* do ser ou coisa, e não o próprio ser ou a própria coisa» [referência omitida].

Encontramos a mesma distinção em [Português: Aposto explicativo não deve ser confundido com predicativo](https://www1.folha.uol.com.br/folha/educacao/ult305u9852.shtml) de Thaís Nicoleti de Camargo (Folha de São Paulo, 17-7-2002).